# fst += (sec - (sec = fst)); нет ли здесь неопределенности?

Tags: java, swap

нормальный ли это способ дать переменным обменяться значениями без использования третьей? fst и sec в шапке обычные int переменные, пишу на java. Выглядит, будто есть неопределенность, но попробовал в пузырьке в качестве swap делать это, и сортировка прошла верно.

Comment: Способ ненормальный хотя бы потому, что неочевидный

Comment: Но если его комментировать каждый раз при вставке в код, то нормально

Comment: @AntonSorokin мне кажется, лучше сразу писать ясный код, чем писать запутанный код и пытаться прояснить его с помощью комментариев.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Неопределенности в коде нет (и я не знаю, может ли она быть вообще в синтаксически правильном коде на `java`). При условии, что `fst` и `sec` -- примитивные числовые типы, этот код действительно осуществляет обмен значений. Другое дело, что это может быть неочевидно и может быть понято неправильно, т.е. код не является **неопределенным**, но является **непрозрачным**. Читаемость, ясность кода -- в подавляющем большинстве случаев важнее, чем его эффективность. К тому же я не думаю, что у такого кода есть преимущество в эффективности перед традиционным

```
  int tmp = a;
  a = b; b = tmp;
```

так что я бы не стал так писать. И я бы не пришел в восторг и не одобрил бы автора, если бы мне пришлось такое читать.

Comment: согласен, в каком-либо проекте так не стоит писать, просто я решал задачки всякие, и одна была придумать, как без третьей переменной свап сделать. Просто появилось подозрение, что в зависимости от того, что раньше подгрузится, может быть разный результат